# How to use input box to enter formula?

Tags: netlogo

I am using NetLog to test learning curve formula.  I would like to use the input box to interactively enter something as simple as
    current-tick * 23
No joy.  I can capture a current ticks value in a set command, but I cannot get the input box to accept a formula.  Once I learn how to do it, I can work out how to do larger formula.

```
  set knowledge-increment []
  set knowledge-increment + learning-equation * 25
```

learning-equation is the label for the input box.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What sort of inputs are you trying so far?

Answer (score 1):

The input box sets the value of the global variable specified. It is a string. To use that string in code, something like this will work

```
run (word "show " learning-equation)
```

or more to your point of setting a value

```
globals [new-equ]
to go
  run (word "set new-equ " learning-equation)
  show (word "new-equ is " new-equ)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in basic form. Now to apply it. The input box called increment, uses a no quotes equation.

I used stuff as a global.

The code line contains the set command within the quotes. Now I can use stuff as a constant as in:

run (word “set stuff ” increment)

show stuff * ticks

I just have to avoid using global variables such as ticks in a turtle setting.
Thank you Lon and Andrew